# IIS hang state

Tags: multithreading, iis, freeze

Any suggestion to detect flaws in VB6 components running under IIS. IIS becomes unstable and after some time enter in a state of hang. The problems occur in the most part only in the production environment. We have many modules running. Probably there are components with bugs and need to identify them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done this, but you can set up the VB6  components in the DCOM snap-in and insist that they're only accessible by one thread at a time. 
I had to do this for a VB6 component one time to make it play nicely with classic asp.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to watch out for is multi-threading issues.  VB6 components often don't play well when accessed by multiple threads.

If the client code is an ASP.NET application consider putting synchlocks around the calls to ensure that they are called sequentially.

Another sure-fire way to fubar IIS is to display a message box or initiate some other sort of user interaction.  Get those MsgBox calls outa there.

Other than that... good logging helps.  VB6 is pretty opaque when errors arise.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) to analyze a dump of IIS. [Tess' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/pages/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx) is one of the best resources to learn to use WinDbg. Although she focuses on .NET debugging, most of the material is applicable to any Win32 process.